# Add second expression to query

Tags: 7, database

I have a probably trivial question, but I could not find an answer.
I have this query, which works fine:

```
$query = db_select('books, 't');
$query
  ->fields('t', ['publication_year'])
  ->groupBy('t.publication_year')
  ->orderBy('publication_year', 'ASC')
  ->addExpression('COUNT(t.publication_year)', 'n');
$data = $query->execute();
$result = $data->fetchAll();
```

I want to add a second expression:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE open_access=1) AS n_oa
```

But I have two problems:
When adding a second expression I get the error `Method 'addExpression' not found in null|string` regardless of the content.

When only adding the single expression `->addExpression('SELECT COUNT(*) from books WHERE open_access=1', 'n_oa');` I get a syntax error.

Edit:

I tried this, and it generally works except, that the seond expression can't find the 'year' alias.

```
 $query
    ->addField('t', 'publication_year', 'year');
  $query
    ->condition('wg', 'ag_zzexternal', '=')
    ->groupBy('t.publication_year')
    ->orderBy('publication_year', 'ASC')
    ->addExpression('COUNT(t.publication_year)', 'n');
  $query
    ->addExpression('SUM(IF(open_access=1,1,0) AND IF(publication_year=year,1,0))', 'n_oa');
}
```

Comment: The return from addExpression() is an alias, so it can't be chained. You can add a second expression using $query->addExpression(). I have never tried adding a nested select this way but perhaps someone else can help with that.

Comment: Maybe try SUM(IF(open_access=1,1,0)) or SUM(open_access) instead?

Comment: Thanks, this generally worked. I now want to expand the expression, but the expression cant find the alias i declared before. Is there a way to make it work? (see my edit part in the question).

Comment: Nevermind, i do not need the alias, i can just use `t.publication_year`, just like in the expression before.